# Neo4j driver for .Net strange result

Tags: .net, neo4j

Why Neo4j cypher query:
 `match (a) return a`
running over driver for .Net return only nodes, but default Neo4j browser return nodes and relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser has a setting (enabled by default) that makes an additional query for all the relationships between resulting nodes of a query. You can toggle that option on the settings tab on the lower left (it's a checkbox at the bottom labeled 'Connect result nodes').

If you want relationships from your queries, you'll need to include that in your MATCH and return.